# Unix makefile error: 'make: Fatal error: Don't know how to make target '

Tags: c, unix, makefile

I have the simplest of makefiles:

```
threads:
   gcc threads.c -o threads
```

but I get the error:

> 'make: Fatal error: Don't know how to make target'

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  It's probably something simple - I made the makefile in emacs on the system which is trying to run it (Unix)

Comment: How do you invoke make? Just 'make threads'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have spaces instead of a tab on the second line there? Most common basic make mistake, I'd say.

Comment: It is a common error, but you should get a different error message.

Comment: Ah, you're right - I was thinking it prevented the rule from getting defined. My bad. But it got accepted... maybe it was somehow right?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

<strike>Did you mistype the make as you got the error 'ake: Fatal error....', something is wrong there.</strike>

Does `make threads` work? You need to show us the make file for us SO'ers to see what is wrong...Perhaps the make file is not in the right way, Make is extremely nitpicky on using spaces and tabs so double check on that.